# Cannot refer View Ids of included xml from parent xml in android data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I am trying to refer viewIds of included `xml` in my parent layout using Android's data binding.
But it shows this particular error

```
 Error:(136, 36) Could not find accessor databinding.idName
```

I am able to access the id's within the same layout but not in the included one.

I have already tried this [Cannot refer to other View ID in Android data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727600/cannot-refer-to-other-view-id-in-android-data-binding)

It works only for the above mentioned case not for included layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MainDataBinding binding = MainDataBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
binding.your_included_layout_id.the_id_you_want_to_access
```

Comment: i want to access it in my xml. not in my activity .. anyways thanks