# Databinding with visibility referencing another ID

Tags: android

I am trying to change the visibility of an element referencing the ID of another element with DataBinding, it works at the first time (onCreate), but if the visibility change in runtime, it does not work.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAnother"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.buttonClicked()}"
        android:visibility="@{buttonView.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />


fun buttonClicked() {
    activity.runOnUiThread {
        val buttonView = activity.findViewById<ButtonView>(R.id.buttonView)
        if (buttonView.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            buttonView.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            buttonView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I was thinking it was possible but because there is not internal binding, it won't work.

Related by:

[Cannot refer to other View ID in Android data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727600/cannot-refer-to-other-view-id-in-android-data-binding)

Comment: Post the code inside buttonClicked method

Comment: @IshanFernando done, it just hide the button