# Data binding passing xml element with special characters

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

Consider the following bindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter({"pager"})
public static void bindViewPagerTabs(final TabLayout view, final ViewPager pagerView)
{
    view.setupWithViewPager(pagerView, true);
}
```

and the setting in the xml is :

```
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_control_tab_layout"
            style="@style/tab_in_toolbar_style"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:pager="@{(pager_r)}"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Gives the following error :

```
error: cannot find symbol class ActivityCardControlBindingImpl
```

But if I changed the pager Id to anything without the underscore  or any special characters like `@+id/pager` it works perfectly, any valid reason ?

Comment: I don't think anybody can answer this, Please report this to google on https://issuetracker.google.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot refer to other View ID in Android data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727600/cannot-refer-to-other-view-id-in-android-data-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you write `app:pager="@{(pagerR)}"` instead of `app:pager="@{(pager_r)}"`. Also you don't need the brackets, so you could just write `app:pager="@{pagerR}"`.

EDIT:

> But if I changed the pager Id to anything without the underscore or any special characters like @+id/pager it works perfectly, any valid reason ?

I don't know about other special characters, but when you use the underscore in your view ids the snake case view ids like "pager_r" get converted by databinding to camel came variables like "pagerR". So as my original answer states, if you use @+id/pager_r you can use the variable pagerR.

Comment: this is not an answer , this was part of the question !

Comment: No it was not part of your question: You wrote that if you use the id @+id/pager you can use the variable pager, but that you can't use the variable pager_r if you use the id @+id/pager_r. What I am telling you is, that you can use the variable pagerR if you use the id @+id/pager_r, because snake_case view ids get converted to camelCase variables by the databinding library. I edited my answer with the information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same answer as Janosch Pelzer's with a litte more explsnation here

[Cannot refer to other View ID in Android data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727600/cannot-refer-to-other-view-id-in-android-data-binding)